# Adding new node to existing corda network

Tags: corda

Am trying to add new node with existing node in corda network. I did as documentation. But couldn't achieve.

1. Is that enough to create a folder with node.conf as mentioned in documents. If then its not updating the data and info in the folder while running bootstrapper. But I can achieve this by adding corda and corda webserver with node.conf file.
2. What will happen to ongoing transactions from existing node while adding new node to the network?
3. Do I want to add any other corda jar to the cordapps folder which is present in the new node folder? I checked in other node folder and found corda jars under cordapps folder. Is that fine to not having those jars in new node folder?

Answer (score 1):

Please note -

1. New node should have same folder structure as existing ones.
2. Node.conf, certificates, additional-node-info files may be different for each node.

If you are running in dev mode, then it is advised that you should recreate the network using **"gradlew.bat deployNodes"** command. This will redeploy all nodes including the new one.

If you are running in production mode, then you have use network map - "https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html".

```
1. Is that enough to create a folder with node.conf as mentioned in documents. If then its not updating the data and info in the folder while running bootstrapper. But I can achieve this by adding corda and corda webserver with node.conf file.
```

Ans: You may have to copy the corda jars present in other nodes to the new node.

```
2. What will happen to ongoing transactions from the existing node while adding the new node to the network?
```

Ans: Before a node or application on it can be upgraded, the node must be put in Draining mode. This brings the currently running Flows to a smooth halt such that existing work is finished and new work is queuing up rather than being processed.

https://docs.corda.net/node-upgrade-notes.html?highlight=draining

```
3. Do I want to add any other corda jar to the cordapps folder which is present in the new node folder? I checked in other node folder and found corda jars under cordapps folder. Is that fine to not having those jars in new node folder?
```

Ans: No. The new node should have all corda jars present in other nodes.